# Missing messages using queue-outbound adapter of redis to distribute task

Tags: redis, spring-integration

I am using the two components provided with s.i. to have a working distribution system

Messages (tasks) are sent to this channel named distribution; distribution has a wire-tap associated to a notification system so I can see vía jconsole or mission control when a message goes through distribution:

```
  <int:channel id="distribution">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="distributionPublish"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
```

Then I use redis as a queue system:

```
  <redis:queue-outbound-channel-adapter
            id="toRedis" channel="distribution" queue="Qname"
            auto-startup="true" extract-payload="false"  />


    <!-- a Queue Inbound Channel Adapter is available to 'right pop' messages
        from a Redis List. -->
    <redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter
            id="fromRedis" channel="execution" queue="Qname"
        receive-timeout="1000" recovery-interval="1000" expect-message="true"
            auto-startup="true"/>
```

With the below configuration and 2 servers, each take 50% of messages; Mainly one server has a web service interface and puts the message into the input queue, and then all servers that are subscribed and blocked are getting the messages (tasks)

But when I speed up the system there are messages losts. I don't know why, and I don't know what can I do. I have increase the redis pool values and this issue continue,

Am I doing something wrong, or how can I implement a "retry" in the distribution component?

PD: I have wire-tap to be sure about the error is in the distribuion component

UPDATED

Maybe this configuration can help? (still not tested, will update when I did)
The idea is to have several threads going to redis

```
  <int:channel id="distribution">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="DistributionTaskExecutor"/>
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="distributionPublish"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
    <!-- to handle high demanding we use several threads to go to redis -->
    <task:executor id="DistributionTaskExecutor" pool-size="2" />

    <redis:queue-outbound-channel-adapter
            id="toRedis" channel="distribution" queue="${instance}"
            auto-startup="true" extract-payload="false"  />
```

Updated:

Finally, I am using this configuration and seems to be working well or. at least, better:

```
 <int:channel id="distribution">
        <int:queue capacity="50"/>
    </int:channel>

    <task:executor id='distributionExecutor' pool-size='25' queue-capacity='25' rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

    <redis:queue-outbound-channel-adapter
            id="toRedis" channel="distribution" queue="${instance}"
            auto-startup="true" extract-payload="false">
        <int:poller task-executor='distributionExecutor' fixed-delay='500'>
        </int:poller>
    </redis:queue-outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Do you lose messages, if you have only one subscriber server?

Comment: I've edited the post trying to explain better;... I lost in the "distribution" (the message actually is not sent to the queue) not in the reception. Or this is my suspect...

Comment: ops! before the distribution I have a header-value-router with resolution-required=true .... maybe I am missing the messages in this component. In the doc I am reading that to use the default-output-channel resolution-required should be false..

Comment: ??? Does it fix your issue ? So you just haven't shown entire config

Comment: Well, this is only reproducible in production and in high demanding peaks, so I cannot test now. Is it posible (for your question) that the message is lost when 2 consumers of the redis queue are competing for righ pop the message?

Comment: If you think that `resolution-required=true` is a root of cause and your logic relies on `default-output-channel`, so just switch off `resolution-required` and go ahead to the production.

Comment: Not working; still I lost task in the "lpush" to redis; as this problem is only in high load, I am thinking the direct channel is losing the message when the queue-outbound is busy.... sounds rigth? Any improve? a task-executor, or a load-balancer or anything in this way?

Comment: You config shows very low concurrency for the `task-executor`. And from here your `distribution` is an `ExecutorChannel` not dirrect. If your Redis so busy to apply so many messages the `task-executor` might end up with `RejectedExecutionException`, because the thread pool is exhausted. Really try to use just a `DirectChannel`, or change the policy to `CallerRunsPolicy`

Comment: I update the question with a configuration that up to now seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish this question I move my comments here as an answer.

Since the `<task:executor/>` configuration has had very low concurrency (2) and with `AbortPolicy` as default one, the task to execute against Redis have been lost because of `rejection`.

There is need just to rely on the single-threaded `DirectChannel` or ensure enough big thread-pool for the task-executor and configure policy to `CallerRunsPolicy`.